# ExpressionEngine 1 - Fieldtype to select members

Tags: members, ee1, fieldtype

My client has an old site that is using EE 1.6.8. They need to be able to select multiple members from a list to display member field information about them. Before I went and created something using queries, I thought I would ask and see if anyone knew of an existing fieldtype of such thing.

The entry template would be pretty simple. Just a simple copy field with a gallery of employee photos. Only some of the employees will be listed though.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/vz-members may help you out - it's a fieldtype for selecting one or members